# Edit selected shape with a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a simple program to edit an image drawn with shapes. I have one JFrame that displays a "face" and another that displays a tool bar. I am trying to link it so a selected shape in the 'face' class can be manipulated by a button on the toolbar. I have the following lsitener:

(EDITED)

Here's what I have with the updates provided... I tried to implement it but am still not getting it (Sorry for the bulk code):

```
public class FaceClass extends JFrame {


private static Face face;

//Face face = new Face();//create a face object
private JScrollBar jscbHort = new JScrollBar (JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
private MessagePanel messagePanel = new MessagePanel ("Face Class");

public FaceClass () {

    this.face = new Face ();
    JButton colorChange = new JButton ("Change Color");

    //add buttons to panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    panel.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(colorChange);
    add(jscbHort, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    add(panel);

    //Register Listeners
    ColorListenerClass listener = new ColorListenerClass();

    colorChange.addActionListener(listener);

    jscbHort.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            double value = jscbHort.getValue(); //returns current value 
of scrollbar 0-100
            double maximumValue = jscbHort.getMaximum();
            double newX = (value * messagePanel.getWidth() / 
maximumValue);
            messagePanel.setXCoordinate((int)newX);

        }//end adjustment Value Changed

    });//end adjustment listener */



    //register mouse click activity
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event) {
                    face.selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event) {
                    face.selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });

}//end cons


/*************EnlargeListener Class**********************************/
class ColorListenerClass implements ActionListener{


    @Override// necessary to respond to the event
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        Face face = face.getFace();//THIS LINE KEEPS GIVING ME ERRORS
        //System.out.println("Color Button Clicked");
        if (face.getSelected() == face.getHead()){
            System.out.println("Face is selected");
        }//end if
        else if (face.getSelected() == face.getMouth()){
            System.out.println("Mouth is selected");
        }//end if
        else if (face.getSelected() == face.getEyeLeft() || face.getSelected() ==      
face.getEyeRight()){
            System.out.println("Eyes are selected");
        }//end if
        else 
            System.out.println("Nothing is selected");

    }//end actionPerformed

}//end OKListenerClass




//////////////MAIN////////////////////////////////////////    
public static final void main (String[] args) {

        //draw face panel
        //Face face = new Face();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Mugshot");
        frame.add(face);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        //draw toolbar panel
        JFrame frame1 = new FaceClass ();
        frame1.setTitle("Toolbar");
        frame1.setSize(200,150);
        frame1.setLocation(200,100);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);  


}//end main
}//end face class
```

And the 'Face':

```
public class Face extends JPanel{

///Instance Variables   
private final Shape head = new Ellipse2D.Float(100, 20, 300, 300);//head component
private final Shape eyeLeft = new Ellipse2D.Float(152,85, 80, 55);//left eye
private final Shape eyeRight = new Ellipse2D.Float(265,85, 80, 55);//right eye
private final Shape pupilRight = new Ellipse2D.Float(285, 85, 40, 55);//right pupil
private final Shape pupilLeft = new Ellipse2D.Float(172, 85, 40, 55);//left pupil
private final Shape mouth = new Rectangle2D.Float(180, 230, 140, 20);//mouth
private Shape selected = null;

private Face face;

public Face () {
    this.face = face;


    //register mouse click activity
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event) {
            selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event) {
            selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    });

}

 protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);  
         Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;

        graphics.setColor((selected == head) ? Color.CYAN : Color.GREEN);
        graphics.fill(head);

        graphics.setColor((selected == mouth) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.RED);
        graphics.fill(mouth);

        graphics.setColor((selected == eyeLeft || selected == eyeRight) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fill(eyeLeft);
        graphics.fill(eyeRight);

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fill(pupilLeft);
        graphics.fill(pupilRight);
        g.drawLine(220, 185, 270, 185);
        g.drawLine(220, 185, 260, 130);



    }//end pC

    public Face getFace() {
        return face;
    }

    public Shape getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }//end getSelected

    public void setSelected(Shape selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }//end setSelected

    public Shape getHead() {
        return head;
    }//end getFace

    public Shape getEyeLeft() {
        return eyeLeft;
    }//end getEyeLeft

    public Shape getEyeRight() {
        return eyeRight;
    }//end getRightEye

    public Shape getMouth() {
        return mouth;
    }//end getMouth


    public void selectShapeUnder (int x, int y) {
        Shape oldSelected = selected;

        if (eyeLeft.contains(x, y)){
            selected = eyeLeft; 
        }//end if 
        else if (eyeRight.contains(x, y)){
            selected = eyeRight;    
        }//end else if
        else if (mouth.contains(x, y)){
            selected = mouth; 
        }//end else if
        else if (head.contains(x, y)) {
            selected = head;
        }//end else if
        else
            selected = null;
        if (selected != oldSelected)
            repaint();
    }//end selectShapeUnder

}//end Face class
```

Comment: I just edited with where I'm calling that. It's in the face class, and for now I have it where if the shape is clicked or 'selected' it will change the color, but I want to be able to do that with the button, rather than the click itself. Do I need to add that mouseListener to the toolbar class as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you're creating a new `Face` object *inside the `ActionListener`*. So, to walk through that:

1. You click/drag on the face that exists in your frame with the intention of selecting part of it.
2. You click on the toolbar button, hoping to perform logic on the part of the face you just selected.

Inside the listener for the toolbar button, however, you're creating a new `Face` that's local to that method (doesn't have anything selected yet) and treating it as if it's the `Face` you modified in step 1.

You probably want to store a reference to the `Face` that's actually being displayed in your frame as a class field. If you actually have two different frames containing the toolbar and face as you say, you'll want a `getFace()` method on the frame containing the face that you can call from the toolbar frame.

**Edit**

To address your comment a bit, it really depends on how your program is structured. The simplest example would be something like the following:

```
class FaceFrame extends JFrame {
    private Face face;

    public FaceFrame() {
        super();
        this.face = new Face();
    }

    public Face getFace() {
        return face;
    }
}
```

Then in your other frame:

```
class ToolbarFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private FaceFrame faceFrame;
    ...

    public ToolbarFrame() {
        super();
        this.faceFrame = new FaceFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        Face face = faceFrame.getFace();
        if (face.getSelected() == face.getFace()){
            System.out.println("Face is selected");
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably not the optimal design for what you're doing, but it should at least illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: so how would I go about creating a getFace() for the class itself?

Comment: So I'm still a little confused and it's still not working. I'm updating with what I have after trying to implement what you said.

Comment: Got it to work. You're answer got me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Great! I had actually been typing another edit when your comment came in; glad you were able to work it out. My parting tip would be that you might want to consider a different naming scheme—working out which `Face` was which in your code was a little difficult :).

Comment: Yeah haha I am actually in the process of renaming it... I have been playing around on this for a long time and didn't know how many classes I was going to originally use and then I kept adding random test classes and those were the two that it came down to so I am fixing that haha. Not the easiest thing to work with.